# Loading mysql data to a html form and updata with php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I extremely new to both mysql and php (mostly mysql), and i'm not even sure i got all of the basics, cause i'm more of a learning-by-doing-person.
So my code is made up of different explanations all around the web, and some of it might be wrong.
So i'm trying to get data from a database, put it into a html form, edit it, and update the database with the new data.
So far the data gets loaded into the form correctly, and with a lot of troubleshooting i've come to the conclusion that even the upload works out as it should, except the fields are empty. So i guess that my problem must be in getting the data from the form, to the update query.

This is my code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
require 'connect.php';


$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM test") or die ($db->error);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    $name = $row['name'];
    $school = $row['school'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $grade = $row['grade'];
    $workshop = $row['workshop'];
    $id = $row['id'];
?>
<form method="post" action="#">
    <?=$id?>
    <input name="nameid" type="text" value="<?=$name?>">
    <input name="emailid" type="text" value="<?=$email?>">
    <input name="gradeid" type="text" value="<?=$grade?>">
    <input name="workshopid" type="text" value="<?=$workshop?>">
    <input name="schoolid" type="text" value="<?=$school?>">
<?php } 
session_start();
$_SESSION['storage'] = $_POST;
?>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
</form>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{

    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "892847", "123456789", "892847");

    // Check connection
    if($link === false){
        die("Couldn't connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    session_start();

    $name = $_SESSION['storage']['nameid'];
    $school = $_SESSION['school']['schoolid'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email']['emailid'];
    $grade = $_SESSION['grade']['gradeid'];
    $workshop = $_SESSION['workshop']['grade'];
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];


    $sql = "UPDATE test SET name = '$name', email = '$email', school = '$school', grade = '$grade', workshop = '$workshop' WHERE id = '8'";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        echo "Records added successfully. $name";
        print_r($_POST['nameid']);
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }


    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm aware that the session-chaos looks strange, but i read somewhere that a information isn't available across PHP-scripts, unless you make a session.

I'm really grateful for any kind of help - i've been fighting with this for about 48 hours

Comment: You don't need to persist your post in session. And your query will give you more than a row. Since you just need a row, you should select only that row `$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = '$id'") or die ($db->error);`
I assume you have an `id` field in your table and you are getting the `$id` of the row you want to update

Comment: Sorry, but almost everything is in the wrong place in this code. I suggest you change your approach and start with a good book or tutorial

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yeah, it's kind of messed up. But you know, i know how to connect, how to fetch the data, and how to upload, so i thought it'd be easy just to combine that knowledge

Comment: @Orion okay, thanks. I do need to update all the rows though, i just made it simple for testing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic approach, using the easiest procedural php.
First, you load data in from mysql into php array as follows, assuming you've already made the connections and `id` is the id of that specific row

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE `id` = '$id'"));
```

Find a way of ensuring that that page is displaying the required id, for instance, you can use `$id = $_GET[row];` in that case your url will be `http://url?row=id`
In the html code use echo as follows

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['row']" ?>" >
<input type="text" name="nameid" value="<?php echo $row['nameid'] ?>" >
...
</form>
```

Forget about sessions, the moment you press submit it should carry all this data in to the `process.php` in a global variable $_POST or $_GET, depending on which method you chose in the `<form method>`.

Now in the process.php, use

```
$nameid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nameid']);
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE test SET `name_id` = '$nameid' WHERE `id` = '$id'");
if($sql) {
echo "update successful";
}
```

Needless to say, you need to use database connections in both pages.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared statement and parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have demonstrated the easiest method, this should work, but it is very unsafe, users should use more secure method, this is just a basic demonstration